# How to authenticate by smart card as a fallback to windows authentication in httpClint/httpListener

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-authentication, smartcard, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using `Owin` to self host a web application.

The authentication scheme defined at the server is as follows:

```
HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
```

My client's code looks like:

```
using (var webRequestHandler = new WebRequestHandler {UseDefaultCredentials = true})
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(webRequestHandler))
{
    var responseCode = httpClient.PostAsync("https://server:443/myapi/dosomething/", null).Result.StatusCode;
    Console.WriteLine(responseCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ? "Success" : "Failure");
}
```

This works great when the logged-on user on the client's machine is a user known by the server's machine.

The problems begin when, for example, the client's machine is not domain joined and the client is run by a local user. In that case, I have extended my client a bit, as follows:

```
HttpStatusCode responseCode;
using (var webRequestHandler = new WebRequestHandler {UseDefaultCredentials = true})
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(webRequestHandler))
{
    responseCode = httpClient.PostAsync("https://server:443/myapi/dosomething/", null).Result.StatusCode;
}

if (responseCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
{
    string username;
    string password;
    // prompt user for credentials and store them at the above variables

    using (var webRequestHandler = new WebRequestHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password)})
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(webRequestHandler))
    {
        responseCode = httpClient.PostAsync("https://server:443/myapi/dosomething/", null).Result.StatusCode;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(responseCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ? "Success" : "Failure");
```

And this solves it, but I'm limited to perform the fallback authentication using username/password only.

My problem is that I need to support **smart card authentication** as well as username/password authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "smart card authentication" is done via client-side certificates, you can enable this feature either by:

- configuring `HttpClient` to automatically select a certificate

  ```
  var client = new HttpClient(
      new HttpClientHandler{
          ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic
      });
  ```
- or by configuring `HttpClient` with a previously selected certificate

  ```
  var clientHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
  clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
  var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
  ```

where `cert` is a certificate with an associated private key.

You can read more about this on [Client Authentication](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/ch15.html#_client_authentication)